# Übersetzung für “badger cull”

Tags: translation, english-to-german, difference

Der “badger cull” oder auch “- culling” [beschreibt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badger_culling_in_the_United_Kingdom) die systematische Jagd auf Dachse, um deren Population drastisch zu minimieren (siehe Link für weitere Details). Ich habe allerdings Schwierigkeiten, einen adäquaten Begriff im Deutschen zu finden, der “cull” korrekt widerspiegelt. Das Beste, was mir eingefallen ist, ist „Dachs-Schlag“; aber das ist sehr mehrdeutig, da es sich auch auf eine Untergattung der Dachse beziehen könnte oder einen Dachsbau (im Sinne von Verschlag). Die wortwörtliche Übersetzung – Keule – erscheint mir im Deutschen nicht verständlich.

Cull scheint mir auch ein Euphemismus für die beabsichtigte Ausrottung einer spezifischen Art zu sein. Die Übersetzung sollte daher wohl idealerweise auf der gleichen sprachlichen Ebene sein.

Comment: Pons hat eine Reihe von guten Vorschlägen: "to cull an animal - ein Tier erlegen" – "cull - Abschlachten" – Ein weiteres Wort, was du selbst erwähnst: Ausrottung –– Ich denke, man sollte nicht versuchen, die Form "noun1 noun2" ins Deutsche zu übernehmen. Es gibt (oder ich wüsste es zumindest nicht) keine idiomatische Form, dies im Deutschen so kurz auszudrücken. Das muss man wohl umschreiben... mit wahrscheinlich 4-5 Wörtern.

Comment: Ausrottung gibt aber die offensichtliche Absicht, einen euphemisierenden Ausdruck zu verwenden, nur inadäquat wieder. Oder? Eine "Substantiv1-Substantiv1" Übersetzung wäre schon das Gesuchte.

Comment: Ich glaube, Jagd wäre am passendsten... oder wenn's genau sein soll, dann sowas wie "Jagd zur Bestandsbegrenzung" oder "Bestandskontrolle" (bin kein Jäger, kenne den Jargon nicht)

Comment: Dann versuchs eben mit "Erlegung", was ja bei der Jagd ein gängiger Begriff ist. Falls dir dann noch die Bedeutung der Bestandsreduzierung fehlt, musst du das explizit erwähnen. Oder du sagst sowas wie "Dachsbestandsreduzierungsjagd". Also, du kannst es im Deutschen nicht kurz und knapp wiedergeben, du musst so oder so den dahinter liegenden Sinn erwähnen.

Comment: @Em1... es geht nicht um einen Badger sondern um viele viele. Da passt Erlegung nicht "Die Erlegung von 1000 Dachsen."... da würde man doch Tötung sagen.

Comment: Ein Begriff, über den ich neulich gestolpert bin, der nicht ganz passt, aber den ich nicht vorenthalten möchte, ist [*Vergrämung*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vergrämung).

Comment: Mir scheint dieses fachsprachliche cull eine Variante von to kill zu sein, Abschießen/Töten mit dem speziellen Ziel der Bestandsbegrenzung. Man könnte von Bestandspflege sprechen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is "[Keulung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keulung)" which apparently (I'm not an expert myself) describes killing (lots of) animals in order to prevent a disease from spreading.

It is not clear to me to what extent it can be used to describe hunting (as opposed to butchering in a controlled environment) for population control (as opposed to disease control).

Answer (score 4):

In Analogie zu der in den 70er Jahren zum Tollwutschutz durchgeführte und mittlereile aus Gründen des Tierschutzes nicht mehr erlaubte Jagd auf den Fuchs bietet sich an, auch hier den waidmännischen Fachbegriff *[bejagen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bejagen)* zu benutzen.

> Das Bejagen des Dachses / die Bejagung des Dachses

Damit bringt man die gezielte und regelmäßige Jagd auf eine einzelne Tierart zum Ausdruck.

Comment: Abstrakter, aber den Zweck besser ausdrückend ist "Bestandskontrolle"; vielleicht möchte man beides zusammen benutzen, also "Bejagung zur Bestandskontrolle"?

Answer (score 2):

Raphael's suggestion "Keulung" is indeed the technical term used for the culling of entire populations (e.g. all the cows on one farm, or all the sheep of a flock) to prevent diseases from spreading (it was mentioned regularly in the news a couple of years ago).

It is not usually used for the killing of animals for purposes of population control, however. Looking at your Wikipedia link, I see that the culling in this case actually *is* for preventing the spreading of diseases - so go for it.

The suggestions involving "Bestandskontrolle" or, slightly less elegant, "Bestandsreduzierung", are on the right track, too, in my opinion. But I don't see the necessity to force "Jagd" into the phrase, since both expressions usually imply hunting and killing the animals already.

Depending on the context, I'd probably go for trying to use both "Bestandskontrolle" and "Jagd", so that the text as a whole makes it clear what you're talking about. I suspect "Keulen" for most people still sounds more like butchering domestic animals. On the other hand, [hunters](http://www.jaegermagazin.de/aktuelles/detail.php?class=62&objectID=4947) seem to use it in the context we're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Dezimierung

"Die Dachse in der Gegend um Nierdertupfingen wurden dezimiert"

(ursprünglich Bestrafung von Gruppen, bei denen jeder zehnte getötet wurde; heute allgemein für starke Verringerung der Populationsdichte, aber klar ohne Anspruch auf Ausrottung, gebraucht. 'cull' hat eine sehr Ähnliche Bedeutung: Anzahl stark reduzieren, aber nicht auf null)